# Heroku deployment - command not found

Tags: heroku, coffeescript, cloud-hosting, spine.js

I am trying to run an application on heroku.
Although, as soon as it starts, the app crashes. The log shows this:

```
2013-07-20T20:06:20.086425+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-07-20T20:06:27.769210+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `serveup ./public`
2013-07-20T20:06:28.888722+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: serveup: command not found
2013-07-20T20:06:30.942655+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-07-20T20:06:30.973063+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

My Procfile contains this: `web: serveup ./public`

This command should be working, as its provided by a person that is already running this app on heroku. Any suggestions as to what might be causing this?

**Edit**
serveup exists within node_modules/serveup and is installed by npm install .

**Update**

I had to add the following command before deploying the application:

```
heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs
```

I believe it was fixed because of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `serveup` doesn't exist on the `PATH` you've got set for your heroku configuration. Assuming it has been installed, you need to either modify your `PATH` variable to include it's location or you need include an explicit path to `serveup` in your Procfile.

Comment: Just curious if you know what setting that environment variable did relative to this problem. Did it end up modifying PATH, modifying the serveup install location, modifying the location specified in the Procfile or something else?  BTW, thanks for the accept. That was generous under the circumstances.